# The problem of my proof? Why doesn't $\mathbb{P}(|Y_i|<\infty)=1$ imply $\mathbb{E}|Y_i|<\infty$?

Tags: probability-theory

Given i.i.d $Y_1, Y_2,\cdots Y_n$, suppose $\mathbb{P}(|Y_n|<\infty)=1$, namely $\mathbb{P}(\{\omega: |Y_n(\omega)\}|<\infty\})=1$, then since $ \{\omega: |Y_n(\omega)\}|<\infty\}\subset\{\omega:lim_{n\to\infty}|Y_n(\omega)/n|=0\}$, we have $\mathbb{P}(lim_{n\to\infty}|Y_n/n|=0)=1$, i.e. $Y_n/n\rightarrow 0$ a.s.

I know this is incorrect because almost sure convergence would imply $\mathbb{E}|Y_i|<\infty$ and it's not always the case. But where is my proof wrong?

Comment: $A \subset B, P(B)=1$ does not imply $P(A)=1$. Besides it is not clear what value of $i$ you are using.

Comment: May be instructive: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/St._Petersburg_paradox

Comment: The inclusion of the two sets above is wrong. Consider the constant random variables $Y_n=n$. Anyways, I don't see how you want to conclude integrability from what you've written above. I suppose you want to use the limit theorems? Well, you need assumptions for these.

Comment: But if $Y_n=n$, the sequence is no longer i.i.d., is there any other counterexamples?

Comment: Let all $Y_n =k$ with probability $6/(\pi k^2)$ for $k \geq 1$.